# How to create a FOR loop for jQuery validate rules?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a `for loop` for the rules on [jQuery validate](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) function, as follows:

```
form.validate({
    rules: {
        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arguments[i]: {required: true,},
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click on submit I get `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` (in jsFiddle) and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (` in firebug. The problem is probably the last comma. I followed the suggestions of Felix and Huangism by removing the last comma but I always get the same error.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GXJV/1/).

Comment: Just press `backspace` on your keyboard?

Comment: What's the error saying? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Click just after the comma and hit back space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not syntactically correct, you can't create an object like string concatenation

```
function x() {
    var rules = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        rules[arguments[i]] = {
            required: true
        };
    }
    form.validate({
        rules: rules
    })

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
form.validate({
    rules: (function() {
        results = {}
        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            results[argument[i]] = { required: true }
        }
        return results;
    })();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

How can I create loop for rules and messages for below code.

```
 $("#quote").validate({ 

 rules : {
  a1_wdad_postcode: {
                              validatepostcode: true
                         },

                         a2_wdad_postcode: {
                             validatepostcode: true
                          }
 },

 messages : {
  a1_wdad_postcode: {
                              validatepostcode: "Postcode is not valid."
                         },

                         a2_wdad_postcode: {
                             validatepostcode: "Postcode is not valid."
                          }
 },



 submitHandler: function(form) {
```